# Prevent data-toggle for child element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've integrated bootstrap modals into a table so that whenever someone clicks a row a modal is opened. The problem I've encountered is that in that row there is a button also with a data-toggle to a separate modal.

```
<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='some-modal'>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td><button data-toggle='modal' data-target='some-other-modal'></button></td>
</tr>
```

I've thought of two possible solutions to this but neither feel that pretty. The first and ugliest would be to add the data attributes to the first two  tags and exclude it on the third, not particularly DRY. The other would be to add some line to the event handler for modals opening and add a condition to prevent it from opening 'some-modal' if the source of the click is the button in the td.

Any simpler solutions out there for this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It's similar to your first solution. I used **JQuery**.
Then I added class **"no-toggle"** to the **last td**.

```
<tr data-toggle='modal' data-target='some-modal'>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td>Something</td>
    <td class='no-toggle'><button data-toggle='modal' data-target='some-other-modal'></button></td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
$("tr td:not(.no-toggle)").attr("data-toggle", 'modal').attr("data-target", 'some-modal');
</script>
```